# how to write a conditional query string using unirest in java

Tags: java, json, httpresponse, unirest, request.querystring

Im trying to get the records with id's greater than 1000 let's say.
and I'm using unirest in java. I've tried to use queryString but it did not work.

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> responsePatientTest = Unirest.get(Util.URL + "/sometable")
            .queryString("Id","> 1000" )
            .basicAuth("user", "pass")
            .asJson();
```

maybe it's because I'm not familiar with unirest. is there a way to do this with queryString? if not,Could you suggest another way?

Comment: What about the server side support? If the backend just don't support this kind of query, unirest, as a http client, really can't do much then.

Comment: you mean how database is actualy implemented? I don't know much about that.in what case I'm able to use a query like this?

Comment: Um, look, you send a request, which must be handled by your backend. To handle the request, the backend must understand what you have sent in the first hand right? I'm now asking if your backend understand a url like `https://my.site/sometable?Id=> 1000`. I seriously doubt if this is the case. If the backend isn't written by you, ask your backend guy for an explaination on their APIs.